# How to mark non-pre-defined functions as functions of a certain variable during calculation of derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If I have some calculation $X=v\cdot\delta$ and I want to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}X$, the result according to Mathematica is $\delta$. Now, I want to define $\delta$ as a function of $v$ but without defining the exact formula because I do not have that as a whole but numerically. Thus, I want the result to be 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}X=\delta+v\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial v}$$
which is just the application of the product formula for derivatives.
How to set some kind of a "flag" or "marker" to prevent Mathematica from deriving $\delta$ after $v$ and saying that the result is always $0$ because the variables are named differently?

Comment: `D[v δ[v], v]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Dt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html):

```
Dt[v δ, v]
```

> δ + v Dt[δ, v]

Or `D` with the option [`NonConstants`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonConstants.html):

```
D[v δ, v, NonConstants -> {δ}]
```

> δ + v D[δ, v, NonConstants -> {δ}]